# How to send List <Latlng> from Service to MainActivity in Android?

Tags: android

In MyService: I check all locations and add to may Arraylist, but how to pass this arraylist to to MainActivity to display a Polyline on Maps. How to do that?

```
ArrayList <LatLng> listLatlng = new ArrayList <LatLng>();
listLatlng.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
```

I was use:
In my service

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listLatlng", listLatlng);
sendBroadcast(this.intent);
```

in Main Activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ArrayList<LatLng> quanghieu = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("listLatlng");
            }
    };
```

Comment: This question has already been asked many times. Just Google "android service communicate with activity".

Comment: @lionscribe I was try many times with many codes in Google but not correct. Please help me with an anwser. Thank!

Comment: what is your service?

Comment: My Service is check location service. i add all location change to my Arraylist, but i don't know how to pass my arraylist to main Activity to display on map.

Comment: @Quang post your code

Comment: @SahilManchanda i was edit and post my code. Thank!

Comment: Does this code work? Getting the broadcast message?

Comment: @cricket_007 this code is not working.

Comment: Okay, did you register the recevier to the activity?

Comment: @cricket_007 I think yes! in my Androidmanifest i was add code:         <service
            android:name=".checkLocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

Comment: That defines the service, not the receiver

Comment: @cricket_007 Sory, so how to do that?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#communicating-with-a-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Hey, is my codes correct?